# Nested classes based on nn.module

Tags: python, class

I have several classes based on nn.module and I want to have data transferred between these classes. Specifically, I need to get data from the first class and add it to a variable in the second class. Afterward, the combined data in the second class is to be added to the third class. My question is that how it is possible to do this process based on parent and child class relationship? Also, other solutions will be welcome.

A simple example is shown below:

```
class A(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in, out):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        
        self.a=function(.....)


def forward(self, x):
       
        x=self.a(x)
            
        return x


class B(nn.Module,A):
    def __init__(self, in, out):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        
        self.b= nn.conv2d(....)
       self.stacked = Function(self.b, A.a)


def forward(self, x):
       
        x=self.b(x) + self.stacked(x)
            
        return x
```

I do not know if this kind of parent and child classes is correct or not when it comes to the nn.module class?

Comment: `self.a(x)` does not seem to make sense since `a` is an integer. In general, you can subclass and then inside `forward` use a call to `super()` like the following: `return super().forward(x) + self.b*x` where `super().forward` dispatches to `A.forward` based on class hierarchy and `A.forward` might do something like `return self.a*x`.

Comment: @a_guest , Thanks for your comment, The self variable of a was a simple example. The question is edited. My question is that the class B needs to read and join with some computations from class A, and class C needs to do this with some variables and computations from class B and so on. But in my case that the argument inside classes is nn.module, how should I handle the super() functions and inheritances. Can you please elaborate your answer in the form of an answer? Thank You.

Comment: Is `self.stacked` relevant to your question? NB: you have a wrong reference there: `A.a` is not defined; and the code  has indentation issues.

Comment: @trincot , Thanks for your comment. I changed the code a little bit to indicate the self stacked is relevant. But the purpose is to indicate the class B(nn.module) has some computations based on some variables that derived from Class A.

Comment: Still the indentation is off, and `A.a` is an undefined attribute. The description at the top uses the term "class" when in fact you seem to mean "instance". Those are two different concepts, and confusion around that can make you write `A.a` -- which doesn't exist.

Comment: @trincot , is it right at the moment? If so, please let me know your suggested solution. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any edit that relates to my comments.

Comment: @trincot , this example is not realistic. Although I don't know how to fix the issue to be a realistic example, could you please express your proposed solution for such a case as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I think you should at least fix the indentation. Surely you can do that? And `in` is a reserved word, which you cannot use as name. Also, you expect arguments to be passed to the constructors, but never pass them, which also is an error. I think you should present your case with realistic code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `super().forward` when `B` inherits from `A`:

```py
import torch


class A(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = torch.nn.conv2d(...)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.a(x)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = torch.nn.conv2d(...)
        self.stacked = Function(self.b, self.a)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.b(x) + super().forward(x) + self.stacked(x)
```

And them similarly for another subclass `C` which inherits from `B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. My concern is that because the class B has nn.module as its argument (class B(nn.module)), does the answer satisfy this case. Also, I tried to indicate that inside the class B there is a at least a variable that is computed based on the class A by editing the question. Please let me know your comment.

Comment: @dtr43 You can just access `self.a` since it's a base class, it has access to the instance attributes set by the parent class, too (see my updated answer). Inheriting again from `nn.module` is redundant since `A` already inherits that; i.e. `class B(nn.module, A)` gives the same result as `class B(A)`. You can use `print(B.mro())` to check the class hierarchy.